# xcodebuild - setting build dir doesn't generate dSYM

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild

I am doing an archive with xcodebuild (xcode 5) through the command line as so:

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyScheme -sdk iphoneos7.0 -configuration Release archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: My ID" -archivePath archive/MyArchive.xcarchive -xcconfig Config/MyReleaseConfig.xcconfig CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$SRCROOT/build/$CONFIGURATION$EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME
```

When I run this, I get my xcarchive generated and console output seems ok. However, when I explore the contents of the archive there is nothing under dSYM. Project settings are verified ok. If I run the same command as above BUT omit the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` bit, I get the dSYM as expected. Do you know if there's a solution for this (i.e. should anything else be set). I want to have control over the build dir.

**EDIT:**

I've tried setting explicitly from command line (as opposed to in my scheme settings):

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT="dwarf-with-dsym"
```

and 
pos-processing to YES. Still no joy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check again build settings. Take a look at **Debug Information Format**, it should have *DWARF with dSYM file*
[image]

For futher information take a look [OS X Man Pages xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)
 and [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)

Comment: Build settings are fine and I get dSYMs when the CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR is removed.

Comment: Try append this: **DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT="dwarf-with-dsym"**

Comment: Only last thing to check: Build Settings -> Apple LLVM compilier 3.1 - Code Generation -> Generate Debug Symbols = YES

Comment: Yup, it is set to YES

Comment: Maybe, in fact, a dSYM file is generated in other place than the .app? Check environment variables, especially DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH and DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME.
To embed the dSYM within the app bundle, just set DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH to $(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH) and DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME to $(EXECUTABLE_NAME).dSYM.

Comment: Setting DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH worked very well :) Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could show more explicitly exactly how you incorporated the `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` into your command.

Comment: `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` was the problem for me as well. Maybe the answer should be updated to include it @ArturKucaj

Comment: The default value of ```DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH``` is ```$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)```.  So if you change the latter, the dSYMs get copied there instead of the .xcarchive.   Overridding ```SYMROOT``` can also change those values.

Answer (score 1):

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyScheme -sdk iphoneos7.0 -configuration Release archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: My ID" -archivePath archive/MyArchive.xcarchive -xcconfig Config/MyReleaseConfig.xcconfig CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$SRCROOT/build/$CONFIGURATION$EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME
```

what's your config about DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT in MyReleaseConfig.xcconfig?

Comment: MyReleaseConfig.xcconfig is the Xcode config ,generally it is generate by cocoaPods,  it record some link information and so on as I read it